# Git: Push a tag to a new remote branch in 1 command

Tags: git

Git push accepts a source and destination refspec as part of the push operation, but I can not seem to push a local tag as a new remote branch in a single command. I am aware I could checkout the tag and then push it, but this should be possible as a single command.

What I've tried:

`git push origin refs/tags/0.0.1:new_branch`

What happens:

```
Counting objects: 1, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 156 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 1 (delta 0)
To '■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■.com/test.git'
  * [new tag]         0.0.1 -> new_branch
```

I've also tried variations of `remotes/origin/master` instead of master, but this also creates a new tag instead of creating a remote branch based on the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git push origin refs/tags/0.0.1^{commit}:refs/heads/new_branch
```

I've found the answer from another answer here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4061542/6669458

Comment: So,  the trick is that you have to add "^{commit}" to the source so that it knows to look at the commit from that tag,  and for the destination,  you have to prefix it with "refs/heads/" so that it makes a branch instead of a tag.

Comment: Based on that post, `git push origin +0.0.1~0:refs/heads/new_branch` did what I wanted.

Comment: Worth noting here that the "^{commit}" or "~0" bit is only required for *annotated tags*; for lightweight tags on the other hand the above works without this extra bit, eg `git push origin 0.0.1:refs/heads/new_branch`

Answer (score 0):

You can always push the tag directly, it will be pushed detached of a branch.

```
git push origin 0.0.1
```

What will happen:

```
Counting objects: 1, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% 1/1), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 685 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.con:group-something/test.git
 * [new tag]         0.0.1 -> 0.0.1
```

If you want to use your ref syntax, it would be as follows:

```
git push origin refs/tags/0.0.1:refs/tags/0.0.1
```

The result is exactly the same.

In both cases you need to be aware that you are pushing a detached head. This means that anyone pulling or fetching will not get this tagged head. You need fetch with the `--tags` param. Otherwise only the tags in branches will be pulled. So only when you do:

```
git fetch --tags
```

You get the "detached" heads referenced by your tags.

```
remote: Counting objects: 6, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), done.
From git@github.con:group-something/test
 * [new tag]         0.0.1 -> 0.0.1
```